# trying to add a conditional statement to jquery animation

Tags: jquery

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webguy262/e5ana/18/

Page loads with default town scene. Hovering map pin changes the scene.

If the mouse stop for ten seconds, the default scene returns.

Trying to only do that if the default scene is hidden. That's because if the default scene is visible, the code runs and it animates that default scene down and back up again.

Here's what I'm trying...

```
if ($('#dt').css('bottom') == '0px') {
var t;
var del = 10000; //Ms delay 
    $(document).mousemove(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        //If the mouse is not moved
        $(".town").animate({
            bottom: '0px'
        }, 500);
        $("#dt").animate({
            bottom: '126px'
        }, 500);
    }, del);
});
}
```

But it does not work. No script errors are thrown and nothing happens to the scenes.

Syntax issue? Not detecting the position of #dt correctly?

Comment: i dont see `a.dt` in you html

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's because you're already inside your function and past the if statement when you call the mousemove. Maybe try something like this:

```
var t
,   del = 10000; //Ms delay 

$(document).mousemove(function(){
    if ($('#dt').css('bottom') === '0px') {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(function(){
            //If the mouse is not moved
            $(".town").animate({
                bottom: '0px'
            }, 500);
            $("#dt").animate({
                bottom: '126px'
            }, 500);
        }, del);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! that works. one thing I notice though is that if I place the mouse over a map pin, and don't move it at all, the timeout function does not run. But if I move the mouse -- even staying on the pin -- it works. Moving the mouse away from the pin after triggering it works too.  It's just the case where you trigger a pin and don't move. Does the mouseenter function somehow prevent detecting an unmoved mouse? That would explain why moving the mouse slightly but staying on the pin triggers the timer function. Thoughts?

Comment: @user2197029 I can't say with much certainty, since I don't really know much about your project. But you could try putting your timeout into an external function, then calling that function on mousemove, and ALSO calling the function on mouseenter and mouseleave (or mouseover and mouseout, which I tend to prefer) for the pin objects. Since your function is already set up to cancel existing timeouts before setting a new one. The effectiveness of that may depend on how big the pins are.